# How to specify the number of decimal places in a double?

Tags: dart

How does one specify the number of decimal places when outputting a string ?

For example, say I have the following:

```
var root3 = 1.73205080757;
```

And wish to output to two decimal places, how do I format the string, similar to how one does so in Java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doubles in dart have a method `toStringAsFixed()` which is easy to use:

If you have :

```
var root3 = 1.73205080757;
```

You can just do:

```
print(root3.toStringAsFixed(2));
```

Output:

1.73